# controlling order of imports in python without changing sys.path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a personal utilities library like so

```
utils/
    __init__.py
    os.py
    sys.py
    string.py
    collections.py
```

I'm deliberately choosing those names.

I hit a problem if, within any of these modules I want to import the standard libary modules with the same names. For example, in my `collections.py`, I want to do

```
import collections
```

where I want this to be the standard library `collections`.  The trouble is
that this imports itself, i.e. `utils.collections` and e.g.

```
   import string
```

will import `utils.string`, etc.

Is there any way around this problem? Presumably modifying `sys.path` is the recommended solution in situations like this. However, this would require, for each module in `utils` that I first do a

```
   import sys
```

and that will import `utils.sys` and not the `sys` that I need. So I'm stuck again.

Comment: Sorry, edited your post by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to prevent these name collisions in the first place. But since you are probably past that point (or simply must use these names for other reasons), you might have to consider using Python 3.x's `absolute_import` instead:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import collections  # imports collections that is on sys.path
from . import collections as utils_collections  # now imports utils.collections
```

By default, Python 2.x will search your package before searching `sys.path`. Unfortunately, in your situation there is no way around this except the route I illustrate above.

Python 3.x, on the other hand, will by default search the absolute directories in `sys.path` unless preceded by a leading dot.

Comment: Very helpful. The differences between imports in python 2.x and 3.x has never been perfectly clear to me. I'm still a bit confused, but less confused now.

Comment: @mjandrews Glad to help! Yes, there are significant differences between imports in 2.x and 3.x. I'm searching for a complete explanation in the docs right now, although perhaps this is part of the problem!

Comment: @mjandrews I suppose [this is the best (slightly dated) explanation](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-23/package-relative-imports) I can find right now. If you are still interested, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks again. That Mark Lutz book is very helpful. It explains some of the subtleties that I was missing.